# SQLite select sum with monthly group by

Tags: android, database, sqlite, date, strftime

I'm searching all over the net to find a solution to this need :
I need to gather the sum of 'amout' data group by month.

What I found is this request:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%m', date), SUM(amount) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " GROUP BY strftime('%m', date)", null);
```

but I'm pulling my hair of since I'm not able to gather any month from this function `strftime('%m', date);`

I found on the net that this could come from a date format within my DB that will not be understood by the function.

The actuel date stored within my DB is : "Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2016"

I use this cursor to check the returned value:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT distinct date, strftime('%m', date) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

In the cursor (checking only the first checking of the cursor) I have:

- cursor.getString(0) = Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2016
- cursor.getString(1) = null

So I correctly gather the date, it's the conversion that's not working.

Edit :
As proposed and as explained, I thought the format could be misunderstood by the function (and obviously it's the case).

This is how I add date to my database:
I use this : `dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");`

and then this line to add the date to my Money object prior to save it into the DB : `dateFormat.parse("01/12/2016")`

Can you helpl me?
Thanks.

Comment: `The actuel date stored within my DB is : "Thu Dec 01 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2016"` Then we have the cause of your bug. You should store your date as a **valid** SQLite TimeString.

Comment: Ok, that what I was thinking, but I tried many ways of parsing, without knowing how to add a valid date, and what is a valid date, SQLite talking? Thanks.

Comment: i.e.: `2016-12-09`. You can search `sqlite timestring` and get to the official docs.

Comment: I will add details to the problem, will be easier to explain

Comment: `I correctly gather the date` But it's in the **wrong format**.

Comment: I added how I add date into my DB, and doing that, I gather the format (wrong) I shown earlier.

Comment: `This is how I add date to my database: I use this : dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");` Which is obviously **not matching any of the correct formats**, don't you agree? Can you try `"yyyy-mm-dd"`, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rotwang who lead me to the format issue, my problem was located into my Database item creator

When I was creating my object, I was just putting the date as stored in my class (java.util.Date date) without formating it.

So the date was always stored with the wrong format. I had to format it during the creation phase. Hereunder the code to create my object and solving my problem.

`dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");` Thanks again Rotwang

And :

```
public void createMoney(Money money) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(TITLE, money.get_title());
        values.put(AMOUNT, money.get_amount());
        values.put(DETAILS, money.get_details());
        values.put(DATE, dateFormat.format(money.get_date()));
        values.put(TYPE_FK_ID, money.get_typeFkId());
        values.put(CONTACT_FK_ID, money.get_contactFkId());
        values.put(REMINDER_FK_ID, money.get_reminderFkId());

        mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
    }
```